# How to change excel copy (ctrl+c) to not add a paragraph in the end

Tags: excel, text, copy-paste

When selecting a cell in Excel and copying the value via (ctrl+v):
[Excel cell copied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0mx2.png)

And then pasting that copied value on any text file or browser form, the resulting pasted text always include a paragraph in the end.

giving the example:
[2 lines of text in a txt file before pasting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu5ki.png)

when pasting the value copied into line 1 the result will be:
[result lines of text in a txt file after pasting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXucP.png)

Expected the value to be copied, and to be able to paste "inline".

Results into a trailing paragraph braking the text where its being pasting into.

How do I stop excel from adding the trailing paragraph when copying something?

Answer (score 1):

I find two different behaviors:

1. click on cell and ctrl+c will behave as you state,

BUT

2. edit cell, copy contents by selecting in the formula bar and pasting that does not add a "return".